# Бьёт ошибку: AssertionError: Event description must be specified при создании погодного приложения через библиотеку pyowm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyowm, openweathermap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Вчера разбиралась с погодным приложением. Код шёл.Добралась до температуру и погоды через несколько дней. Код работал, но...была единственная странность: температура через n-дней шла минусом и значение было около 200.
Сегодня решила вставить фрагменты кода из документации в свой код - возникли ошибки:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\ПРОЕКТЫ\1.21 Lesson_20.py", line 305, in <module>
    one_call = mgr.one_call(lat=lat_m, lon=lon_m, units='metric')                  # единицы измерения метрические
  File "G:\ПРОЕКТЫ\venv\lib\site-packages\pyowm\weatherapi25\weather_manager.py", line 532, in one_call
    return one_call.OneCall.from_dict(json_data)
  File "G:\ПРОЕКТЫ\venv\lib\site-packages\pyowm\weatherapi25\one_call.py", line 100, in from_dict
    alerts = [NationalWeatherAlert.from_dict(item) for item in the_dict['alerts']]
  File "G:\ПРОЕКТЫ\venv\lib\site-packages\pyowm\weatherapi25\one_call.py", line 100, in <listcomp>
    alerts = [NationalWeatherAlert.from_dict(item) for item in the_dict['alerts']]
  File "G:\ПРОЕКТЫ\venv\lib\site-packages\pyowm\weatherapi25\national_weather_alert.py", line 105, in from_dict
    return NationalWeatherAlert(sender, title, description, start_time, end_time, tags)
  File "G:\ПРОЕКТЫ\venv\lib\site-packages\pyowm\weatherapi25\national_weather_alert.py", line 35, in __init__
    assert description, 'Event description must be specified'
AssertionError: Event description must be specified
```

Из документации вставляла: `one_call.forecast_daily[0].temperature('celsius').get('feels_like_morn', None)` для проверки, но даже удалив данный фрагмент кода, ошибки выбивало, как прежде.

В качестве нахождения температуры через несколько дней использовала строки:

```
d = int(input(()))
print(one_call.forecast_daily[d].detailed_status)
print(one_call.forecast_daily[d].temperature('celsius').get('feels_like_morn', None))
```

В VSC идентичная ошибка - проверяла. Хотя VSC установлен недавно!
И даже на реплите -ошибка.
Вчера вечером код работал, а сегодня - нет. Видимо, я не вижу ошибку у себя....что-то в коде будет...

Comment: @Namerek Помогите, пожалуйста:)))

Comment: Может пойти другим путем? Видно уже, что библиотека хромает.

Comment: @Сергей Кох Мне в рабочих целях её нужно использовать, библиотеку эту. Она у меня стоит по программе.

Answer (score 1):

Исправить довольно легко, в строке mgr.one_call() добавляем параметр exclude='alerts'

Comment: Постарайтесь в будущем оставлять немного более развернутые ответы.